# Modifying the adjacency matrix in Python

Tags: python, numpy, networkx

The code generates adjacency matrix of `3x3` network where diagonals are not connected. I want the code to generate adjacency matrix of connected diagonals. I present the current and expected output.

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.grid_2d_graph(3,3)
nodes = {n: i for i, n in enumerate(G.nodes, start=1)}
edges = {i: e for i, e in enumerate(G.edges, start=1)}
A1 = nx.adjacency_matrix(G)
A = A1.toarray()
G = nx.convert_node_labels_to_integers(G)
G = nx.relabel_nodes(G, {node: node+1 for node in G.nodes})
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, pos=nx.spring_layout(G))
A1 = nx.adjacency_matrix(G)
A = A1.toarray()
```

The current output is

```
array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

[image]

The expected output is

```
array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

[image]

Comment: The mistype in suggested output. Expexted adjacency matrix is 

array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]], dtype=int32)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an edge for every non-last node in 2D grid. Also you can easily extend the solution for a non square case.

```
n = 3    
G = nx.grid_2d_graph(n,n)

iifrom = jjfrom = range(n-1)
nnfrom = [(ifrom,jfrom) for ifrom in iifrom for jfrom in jjfrom]
nnto = [(ifrom+1,jfrom+1) for ifrom in iifrom for jfrom in jjfrom]
nnfrom += [(ifrom+1,jfrom) for ifrom in iifrom for jfrom in jjfrom]
nnto += [(ifrom,jfrom+1) for ifrom in iifrom for jfrom in jjfrom]
G.add_edges_from(zip(nnfrom, nnto))

G = nx.convert_node_labels_to_integers(G)
G = nx.relabel_nodes(G, {node: node+1 for node in G.nodes})
A1 = nx.adjacency_matrix(G)
A = A1.toarray()

print(A)
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
```

Comment: That's a helpful answer but why using `numpy` to get a range? Just use the builtin `range` instead.

Comment: indeed, thanks. Fixed for builtin `range`.